# JSON Parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to parse the below from JSON (using the JSON gem) in Ruby:

```
{ 
  "daily": {
    "summary":"Light rain today through Saturday, with temperatures rising to 88°F on Saturday.",
    "icon":"rain",
    "data":[
      {
        "time":1435464000,
        "precipProbability":0.99
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently what I have is this: `forecast["daily"]["data"]`, but I want to get the `precipProbability` for `time` when it is `1435464000`. Any suggestion on how to complete my current JSON parsing query?

Comment: you could write `forecast["daily"]["data"].first['precipProbability']`

Comment: ^ If you can submit as an answer, I will mark this as correct. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Ojash your answer works with the example provided but if anymore elements are added to that array you can't be sure that you'll get the element for the time the OP is looking for.

Comment: very true @LeoCorrea, i'd rather loop it out and display, since its an array you never know ;) and i am pretty much sure that maclover7 didnt mean to query exact same time, my assumption is it may vary, whats needed is the precipitation probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to your query would be

```
forecast["daily"]["data"].first['precipProbability']
```

However I suggest you make it inside a loop as there might be no data or more than one data on the array

```
forecast["daily"]["data"].each do |data|
  puts data['precipProbability'] # or your implementation logic 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `data` field is an array of objects you can access each of it's member's properties like you would any `Enumerable`.

If you want to find the data for the time `1435464000` simply do the following with [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

```
data = forecast["daily"]["data"].find { |d| d["time"] == 1435464000 }
# ensure data exists for time
if data
  data["precipProbability"]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you're looking through an iterable like an array, it's nice to use the methods in the [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html)

In this case, your `data` is an array, and you're looking for objects which match a condition (time = 1435464000), so you're looking for the `detect` method, also known by the more descriptive name `find`.

```
data_on_day_you_want = forecast["daily"]["data"].detect{ |h| h["time"] == 1435464000 }
precip = data_on_day_you_want["precipProbability"]
```

Obviously this can be inlined or broken apart into more methods, but the important thing is the `detect`.  You pass it a block, and it returns the first element of the `data` array which returns `true` for that block.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'Faraday'
require "JSON"

connection = Faraday.new(JSON.file)
response = connection.get

data_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)["daily"]
data_hash.each do |item|
p item

end
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)