# Multiple JSON objects in one file - possible to turn into one object using gsub?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, regex, parsing

I have been giving the task of converting a file with multiple JSON objects into a CSV. To make things a little easier, I have decided to take the objects and try to turn them into one object so I can parse it more easily. Here's my problem: since the data file is just a bunch of arrays with no commas, I cannot use the flatten method. 
The data file looks something like this:

```
[{"field1": "sample1", "field2":"sample2"}]
[{"field3":"sample3", "field4":"sample4"}]
```

As you can see, it's a bunch of arrays with no commas between them.

So my idea is to go through each array, substitute any instances of "][" with ",", and then have my program parse it like that.

So my goal is to have the file look like:

```
[{"field1": "sample1", "field2":"sample2"}, {"field3":"sample3", "field4":"sample4"}]
```

The code I've been trying to use is:

```
data.gsub(/\s(?=[\]\[]), ","/)
```

I'm fairly certain this is something to do with my Regex expression. Being that I'm trying to parse out "][", I've tried using other Regex expressions, but none of them really seem to be doing what I need it to do.

Now this just isn't working. I was thinking of trying to use scan or insert as well, but gsub seemed like the best method of removing those inner brackets and replacing them with commas.

For anyone who would advise to try and use a .foreach loop on the JSON objects, that won't work for me because the .foreach loop will not parse through separate objects in the same file. Maybe I haven't found a method that actually works for multiple JSON objects yet, but if anyone has a method that works, I'll try that out too.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is find the closing bracket followed by a newline and an opening bracket.

```
data.gsub(']\n[', ',')
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried and it worked fine. Just to make sure I am on the same page as you, You have a file in which every line is a string containing an array. Am I right? Can you share a gist containing the file?. I'll try to parse it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is a link to the sample JSON I'm working with: https://gist.github.com/anfperez/a73325cb05d41c4f0770c5115811e28a

Comment: You can just use `JSON.parse` on your original file and ruby will do it for you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100098/json-parsing-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> data.gsub(']\n[', ',')
> ```
>
> Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be working.

That's because only **double-quoted** string expressions are subject to backslash notation and interpolation, thus it has to be

```
  data.gsub("]\n[", ',')
```

--------

The main difference is that double-quoted `String` literals support string interpolations and the full set of escape sequences.

For instance, they can include arbitrary Ruby expressions via interpolation:

```
# Single-quoted strings don't support interpolation
puts 'Now is #{Time.now}'
# Now is #{Time.now}

# Double-quoted strings support interpolation
puts "Now is #{Time.now}"
# Now is 2016-07-21 12:43:04 +0200
```

Double-quoted strings also support the [entire set of escape sequences](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/syntax/literals.rdoc#strings) including `"\n"`, `"\t"`...

```
puts 'Hello\nWorld'
# Hello\nWorld

puts "Hello\nWorld"
# Hello
# World
```

... while single-quoted strings support *no* escape sequences, baring the minimal set necessary for single-quoted strings to be useful: Literal single quotes and backslashes, `'\''` and `'\\'` respectively.